# Error: error endorsing invoke: rpc error: code= Unavailable desc = transport is closing- proposal response: <nil>

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts, chaincode

I am trying to running the network using AWS, and this error is getting.
But already tried with my local system which is working successfully.

and peer logs:

```
2020-04-14 06:42:20.109 UTC [gossip.discovery] getDeadMembers -> WARN 076 Haven't heard from [82 162 175 209 145 26 145 38 134 159 159 135 222 226 145 133 152 124 220 10 156 20 19 108 110 87 66 231 33 186 120 249] for 25.126321702s
2020-04-14 06:42:21.015 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 077 Entering [52a2afd1911a9126869f9f87dee29185987cdc0a9c14136c6e5742e721ba78f9]
2020-04-14 06:42:27.872 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 078 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 52a2afd1911a9126869f9f87dee29185987cdc0a9c14136c6e5742e721ba78f9, Metadata:
2020-04-14 06:42:33.049 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 079 Membership view has changed. peers went offline:  [[peer0.org2.example.com:9051 ]] , current view:  [[peer1.org1.example.com:8051] [peer1.org2.example.com:10051 ]]
2020-04-14 06:43:29.092 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 07a Exiting
2020-04-14 06:46:57.717 UTC [gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN 07b peer1.org2.example.com:10051, PKIid:02f71ad3acd3fd493ea454ee6bdb38baa09459cd710e55e740b704c62c32986f isn't responsive: EOF
2020-04-14 06:46:57.810 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 07c Got error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
2020-04-14 06:46:57.883 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 07d Entering [02f71ad3acd3fd493ea454ee6bdb38baa09459cd710e55e740b704c62c32986f]
2020-04-14 06:46:57.883 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 07e Closing connection to Endpoint: peer1.org2.example.com:10051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 02f71ad3acd3fd493ea454ee6bdb38baa09459cd710e55e740b704c62c32986f, Metadata:
2020-04-14 06:46:57.885 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 07f Exiting
2020-04-14 06:46:57.918 UTC [gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN 080 peer1.org1.example.com:8051, PKIid:cbb558fedc75923c14c0c5c8989af46dcf1020ef057fdf7584e350ea9277a140 isn't responsive: EOF
2020-04-14 06:46:57.918 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 081 Entering [cbb558fedc75923c14c0c5c8989af46dcf1020ef057fdf7584e350ea9277a140]
2020-04-14 06:46:57.918 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 082 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051, PKI-ID: cbb558fedc75923c14c0c5c8989af46dcf1020ef057fdf7584e350ea9277a140, Metadata:
2020-04-14 06:46:57.918 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 083 Exiting
2020-04-14 06:46:57.943 UTC [chaincode] ProcessStream -> ERRO 084 handling chaincode support stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
receive failed
2020-04-14 06:54:27.323 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0ac TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.20.0.9:7051->172.20.0.12:58704: i/o timeout server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.20.0.12:58704
2020-04-14 06:54:27.327 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0ad TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.20.0.9:7051->172.20.0.10:55110: i/o timeout server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.20.0.10:55110
2020-04-14 06:54:27.318 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0ae TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.20.0.9:7051->172.20.0.11:36988: i/o timeout server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.20.0.11:36988
2020-04-14 06:54:27.433 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO
```

ubuntu 18.04
hyperledger fabrics 1.4.6

please guide me.

Comment: Are your peers up and running? I feel they are exiting.

Comment: Hi Chintan, all peers are up and running.

Comment: All peers running on same AWS instance or different instances?
If running on different instances then check if u can access the instances from each other using command `nc -vz IP Port`

Comment: @alpha ,all  peers are running on same AWS instance.